# elasticsearch php client search with date type

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index with mappings type like this:

```
{
  "mappings":{
    "logs_june":{
      "_timestamp":{
        "enabled":"true"
      },
      "properties":{
        "logdate":{
          "type":"date",
          "format":"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And there is many doc in it([image]). When I try to get the docs with search query below it throws SearchPhaseExecutionException .. all shards failed.. bla bla
What is it problem that I must fix ?

```
$queryFilter = '{
                "query":{
                    "filtered":{
                        "query":{
                            "match_all":{}
                        },
                        "filter":{
                            "range":{
                                "logdate":{
                                    "gte":"00/00/2014 00:00:00  "
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }';
            $params['body'] = $queryFilter;
            $params['index'] = 'accesslog';
            $params['size'] = 1000;
            $query = $elasticSearch->search($params);
```

Comment: can u post the complete error message  i.e  SearchPhaseExecutionException  etc

Comment: @keety Hi, issue solved but another thread I need help ini can you check it: any help appreciated Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635828/python-elasticsearch-client-set-mappings-during-create-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain your `SearchPhaseExecutionException` tells you something along the lines of

```
IllegalFieldValueException[Cannot parse "00/00/2014 00:00:00": Value 0 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12]];
```

Try using `"01/01/2014 00:00:00"` in your `range` filter instead, i.e. with a valid day and month instead of `00`, which is not valid. Also make sure to remove the spaces at the end, as it will also cause an error during the date parsing.

Comment: Hi, I know its not the way right but there is no many people able to help such as this problems.. so can you check this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635828/python-elasticsearch-client-set-mappings-during-create-index Thank you.