# python elasticsearch bulk index datatype

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using the following code to create an index and load data in elastic search

```
from elasticsearch import helpers, Elasticsearch
import csv
es = Elasticsearch()
es = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200')
index_name='wordcloud_data'
with open('./csv-data/' + index_name +'.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    helpers.bulk(es, reader, index=index_name, doc_type='my-type')

print ("done")
```

My CSV data is as follows

```
date,word_data,word_count
2017-06-17,luxury vehicle,11
2017-06-17,signifies acceptance,17
2017-06-17,agency imposed,16
2017-06-17,customer appreciation,11
```

The data loads fine but then the datatype is not accurate
How do I force it to say that the word_count is integer and not text
See how it figures out the date type ?
Is there a way it can figure out the int datatype automatically ? or by passing some parameter ?

Also what do I do to increase the ignore_above or remove it for some of the fields if I wanted to. basically no limit to the number of characters ?

```
{
  "wordcloud_data" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "my-type" : {
        "properties" : {
          "date" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "word_count" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "word_data" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [create a mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) that would describe field types.

With the `elasticsearch-py` client this can be done using [`es.indices.put_mapping`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.put_mapping) or `index.create` methods, by passing it JSON document that describes mappings, [like shown in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39362741/116546). It would be something like this:

```
es.indices.put_mapping(
    index="wordcloud_data",
    doc_type="my-type",
    body={
        "properties": {  
            "date": {"type":"date"},
            "word_data": {"type": "text"},
            "word_count": {"type": "integer"}
        }
    }
)
```

However, I'd suggest to take a look at the [`elasticsearch-dsl`](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package that provides [much nicer declarative API to describe things](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html#doctype). It would be something along those lines (untested):

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Date, Integer, Text
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

connections.create_connection(hosts=["localhost"])

class WordCloud(DocType):
    word_data = Text()
    word_count = Integer()
    date = Date()

    class Index:
        name = "wordcloud_data"
        doc_type = "my_type"   # If you need it to be called so

WordCloud.init()
with open("./csv-data/%s.csv" % index_name) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    bulk(
        connections.get_connection(),
        (WordCloud(**row).to_dict(True) for row in reader)
    )
```

Please note, I haven't tried the code I've posted - just written it. Don't have an ES server at hand to test. There could be some small mistakes or typos there (please point out if there are), but the general idea should be correct.

Comment: Thanks  i will try this out and let you know

Comment: I just changed the order as the same order in the file...not sure if it matters and all seems to work fine from what I can tell...here is one of the documents, is the interger type supposed to store with the double quote "word_count" : "12",?---- {
        "_index" : "wordss",
        "_type" : "my-type",
        "_id" : "AVzS4_2-UW5hFY6GiWVj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "word_date" : "2017-06-17T00:00:00",
          "word_count" : "12",
          "word_data" : "cell phone"
        }

Comment: @NareshMG No, it should be stored and returned as a number, not a string (strings would be accepted on input, but coerced to the type mapping defines). It could be that you need to drop existing data *completely* (drop the index) and re-create it anew. Just defining a mapping doesn't update already existing data. If you didn't do so, you'll have mixed-type data in your DB.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. @drdaeman's Solution worked for me. Although, I thought it's worth mentioning that in elasticsearch-dsl 6+

```
class Meta:
     index = "wordcloud_data"
     doc_type = "my-type"
```

This snippet will raise `cannot write to wildcard index` exception. Change the following to,

```
class Index:
   name = 'wordcloud_data'
   doc_type = 'my_type'
```